# Use a carousel as a form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm working on a object where as part of a form I'd like the user to be able to select from a number of images in a carousel. I can then access the index of the carousel using come javascript, though I'm not sure how to then pass that to the model when the form is submitted?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  function submit(){
    carouselIndex = $('.carousel-inner').find('.active').index()
    console.log(carouselIndex)
    //hiddenInput.value=selectedImageInCarousel;
    return validateForm();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function submit(){
    //Preexisting code
    hiddenInput.value=selectedImageInCarousel;
    return validateForm();
}
```

This should work. Should.

Hiddeninput would be a hidden disabled text input, which has its value set to the selected image's name/id/whatever on form submit.

If this doesn't work, try changing the hidden input's value on click of the image carousel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've added:

      function submit(){
        carouselIndex = $('.carousel-inner').find('.active').index()
        console.log(carouselIndex)
        //hiddenInput.value=selectedImageInCarousel;
        return validateForm();
      }

I thought this would print the current index of the carousel when the submit button is pressed but it doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: The code should work since if I put the print statement in another event listener it prints the index.

Comment: @user2320239 As suggested, try putting the code in the onclick handler for the carousel, and just submit the form regularly; the hidden disabled element will update before submit is called that way, so it should work more reliably.